# Google Cloud Storage install

Tags: google-cloud-storage, java

I need to configure Google Cloud Storage for a Google Apps account, is it possible?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are to actually trying to achieve?

Comment: well i'm trying to use google cloud storage . I wont set up google cloud storage using an ordinary gmail account but a google apps account so as all users of the company will have the possibility to access to the cloud storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sign in as your employee@company.com account, navigate to the [API Console](http://code.google.com/apis/console) and create a project. This project will be part of your apps account.

Add the appropriate other_employee@company.com emails to the team, enable cloud storage in the services tab and you should be all set!